# Merge two observables and use data from both

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have two variables that need to be passed to a function that returns an observable and the values returned from subscribing needs to be passed as two parameters for another function.

I have this working currently like this:

```
...
let headlineDone = false;
let paragraphDone = false;

   convert(headline).subscribe( function(convertedHeadline) {
       headline = convertedHeadline;
       headlineDone = true;
       if (paragraphDone) {
          doSomethingWithThese(headline, paragraph);
       }
   });

   convert(paragraph).subscribe( function(convertedParagraph) {
       paragraph = convertedParagraph;
       paragraphDone = true;
       if (headlineDone) {
          doSomethingWithThese(headline, paragraph);
       }
   });

...
```

This works by running both and only calling the `doSomethingWithThese` function if the other one is complete (they are both done), but I just feel like there should be a cleaner way to do it with merging or something similar, but I haven't really figured out a way to do it that would allow me to access the two values for one function call like that.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a similar behavior use **combineLatest**:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  convert(headline),
  convert(paragraph)
)
.subscribe(([convertedHeadline, convertedParagraph]) => 
  doSomethingWithThese(convertedHeadline, convertedParagraph)
);
```

Comment: Extra note: the selector parameter from a lot of rxjs operators will be removed in rxjs 6.x.x, so I would advice against its use

Comment: Thanjs @Jota.Toledo. Good to know. I updated my answer